# Newbie: Checking to see if radio button is checked on form initialization. What does this code mean?

Tags: javascript

I am a javascript novice. I'm trying to build a complex form whilst simultaneously learning JS and JQ... not an easy task. This code works, but I don't know what two lines do, so I thought I'd ask here.

What this code does is loop through an array to see if a radio button checkbox has been checked as yes or no. It runs at initialization when a user revisits the form he/she is filling out. The code is attached to a textfield element which unhides if myRadioButton is yes, stays hidden if no.

I do not know what lines 5 and 6 do (beginning with the second if statement). Would some knowledgable person please be so kind as to transcribe those lines into a couple of sentences, kind of like they do in tutorials? I would really appreciate it!

```
var rbVal = "";
var rbBtn =  JQuery("[name=\"myRadioButton[]\"]");
for (var i = 0; i < rbBtn.length; i++)
 if (rbBtn[i].checked) {
  if (rbVal != "") rbVal += ",";
   rbVal += rbBtn[i].value;
 }
if( rbVal != "yes" ){
  doSomething;
  } 
 else {
  doSomethingElse;
  }
```

Comment: WOW! The speed of response is unbelievable and so in-depth. It is greatly appreciated! James Allardice, I especially appreciate you going one step further and explaining the DOM info. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That code is checking all radio buttons with a shared name `myRadioButton[]`, to make sure that if one is checked its value is added to `rbVal` string seperated by a comma.

`var rbBtn =  JQuery("[name=\"myRadioButton[]\"]");` <- gets an array of radio buttons

`for (var i = 0; i < rbBtn.length; i++)`  <- loops through every button in that array.

`if (rbBtn[i].checked) {` <- if the button is selected it then checks to see if `rbVAl` is already set.  <-- Either you are missing something here or it is faulty program

Answer (score 0):

Line 5 compares the value of `rbVal` to an empty string (`""`). If `rbVal` is not equal (`!=`) to an empty string, a string containing a comma character is appended to `rbVal`. So for example, if `rbVal` contains the string "hello", after the execution of that line, it will contain "hello,".

Line 6 then appends the value of `rbBtn[i].value` to `rbVal`. `rbBtn` is an array-like object (in fact, it appears to be an instance of jQuery containing whatever was matched by the selector), and when you access a jQuery object with array syntax like that, you get the actual DOM element rather than another jQuery object, so the `value` property is the actual `value` property of the DOM element (by the look of it, that will be a radio button).

So, if you have a radio button like this:

`<input type="radio" value="someVal">`

then your loop would result in `rbVal == "someVal"`.

If you have two radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" value="someVal">
<input type="radio" value="anotherVal">
```

then you would end up with `rbVal == "someVal,anotherVal"`. You can see from that what the overall purpose of that loop is - to build up a comma-separated string of the values of all the radio buttons matched by the jQuery selector.

Comment: Although your response was very helpful, I'm confused about the whole rbVal variable. It would seem to me that appending rbBtn to rbVal would always result with something other than "yes" or "no" (the two values of the myRadioButton"). So, in your analogy above, `rbVal == "someVal,anotherVal"` would never result in a simple yes or no for rbVal. Would you (or someone) care to elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Curiously, this is using jQuery to grab radio buttons and some vanilla JavaScript to see if the returned radio buttons are checked or not.

- `var rbVal = "";` initalises a new variable with an empty string `""`.
- `var rbBtn =  JQuery("[name=\"myRadioButton[]\"]");` fetches all elements from the document that are called `myRadioButton[]`.
- `for (var i = 0; i < rbBtn.length; i++)` loops through each of the returned elements (there might be more than one as `myRadioButton[]` is an array of radio buttons hence the `[]` at the end). `i` is the current index in the array of returned elements.
- `if (rbBtn[i].checked)` sees whether the radio button is "checked" ("on", if you like).
- `rbVal += rbBtn[i].value;`: If the current radio button is checked (remember, `for()` loops through them all), fetch it's `value` attribute and append it (add it onto) whatever is currently in `rbVal`.
  For example, if `rbVal` contains `Hello` and the radio button's value is `world` then `rbVal` would end up containing `Hello world`.
- `if( rbVal != "yes" )` If the value in `rbVal` doesn't equal (`!=`) `yes`, then we call the `doSomething` function.
- If `rbVal` *does* contain `yes`, then we want to call the `doSomethingElse` function:

  ```
  else {
      doSomethingElse;
  }
  ```